# Is Node.js production-ready on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, v8, iocp, libev

In the new 0.5.1 branch, there is an official Windows executable of Node.js. The Linux version of Node.js uses established libraries such as v8, libev, libeio.

Since libev and libeio is for *NIX platforms; is the Windows port of Node.js ready for production use, or is it only for development?

Comment: not trolling.. just honestly curious..  why on earth would you ever want to run that on Windows in production?  What benefit could it possibly bring?

Comment: @Noli hardware re-use. Ship it now. Agile development. YAGNI. If you got some windows boxes, don't buy some linux boxes until you need them. There are many short term reasons for doing it _right_ now. I can't think of any reasons to _not_ migrate to linux in the future though.

Comment: I don't see how any of those reasons listed point to Windows over linux..   Moreso the contrary.  It seems more like adding a potential WTF to the equation, which will go further towards catastrophe than stability.  Seems more reasonable to me to minimize the uncertainties as much as possible by using massively tried and tested systems (i.e. Linux)   But, maybe its just me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0.5.x branch is unstable. Even branch numbers are stable and odds are unstable, so you will have to wait for the 0.6.x if you want it production ready and stable.

Answer (score 2):

Version 0.5.1 is marked unstable, so don't expect this to be production quality. Microsoft seems to back the Win32 port of Node however, so in the (near?) future it will be stable.

Comment: Some more information: http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%E2%80%99s-help/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the Windows version of Node.js (0.5.1). It actually works very well, but I couldn't load "child_process" module. It seems that it was not shipped with the current version.

Just my two cents.

**Updated:**
[Here is the TODO.Win32, which answers my questions.](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/TODO.win32)

Comment: Hey George, I'm trying to play around with this but when I try to run a js file with one line of console.log('Hi');, I only get the ellipsis returned and nothing else. I'm running windows 7 Home premium 64 bits. Any idea what could be wrong?